# POST method of API: How to pass an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My API request for a certain addition to add something with the following format:

```
 {
  "name": "good night",
  "actions": "[{ \"deviceId\": \"c39181d52abe5555\", \"actionName\": \"turnOff\", \"params\": [], \"meta\": \"{}\" }, { \"deviceId\": \"f597c13717008fb1\", \"actionName\": \"armStay\", \"params\": [\"1234\"], \"meta\": \"{}\" }]",
  "meta": "{}"
}
```

So I made the following:

```
static postRoutine(nombre, action) {
      return $.ajax({
      url: api.routines.url,
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      timeout: api.timeout,
      data: {'name': nombre, 'actions': action, 'meta': "{}"},
      })
    }
```

**What I don't know is how to build 'action'?? I mean it's suppossed to be an array with a string inside or what?**

I was doing this but it doesn't work:

```
 var actions = [];
 var action1 = "{ \\\"deviceId\\\":  "; "\\\"" + item1.id + "\\\", \\\"actionName\\\":  \\\"" + action + "\\\",  \\\"params\\\":  [], \\\"meta\\\": \\\"{}\\\" }";
 actions[0] = action1;
 api.routines.postRoutine(rut_name, actions).done(function(data){
                              ...//blah blah blah
                             });
```

Basically I was putting a string inside the first position of actions and the pass actions to the method.

UPDATE:  THIS IS WHAT WORKED

```
 var actions = [{"deviceId": item1.id, "actionName": action, "params": [], "meta": "{}"];
```

Comment: Instead of running the gauntlet of escaping double quotes, use single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **JSON.stringify()**

```html
var arrActions  = [{deviceId: 'c39181d52abe5555'}];
var strActions = JSON.stringify(arrActions);
console.log(strActions, typeof strActions);
```

Comment: thank you, I adapted what you told me and it worked!